# Not able to load image in by using .html(text) method of jQuery in django/ChatterBot example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, chatterbot

**ChatterBot Training data set**

**image_data.yml:**

```
categories:
- myown
conversations:
- - show me famous book image?
  - <img src="{% static 'img/Book.png' %}"  height="50" width="50"> //this line is sent as **text** in $row.html(text);
```

**jQuery code:**

```
  function createRow(text) {
    var $row = $('<li class="list-group-item"></li>');

    $row.empty().html(text); //$row.html(text); #Both are not working
    $chatlog.append($row);
  }
```

**app.html:**

```
{% load staticfiles %} //on top of file
...
..
...    
<ul class="list-group chat-log js-chat-log">
    //here <li class="list-group-item"></li> element will appended.
                            </ul>
```

**Error:**

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'img/Book.png'%20%%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Problem is, it is not considering `{% load staticfiles %}`. That's why it's not rendering my image. Can any one help me in this?

**Note:**
If I provide online image link as source, it's working.
But, when I try to give complete local path, for that it is giving 
`not allowed to load local resource` error in chrome console.

Comment: Looking at the `GET` request, can you check to see if the url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%%20static%20'img/Book.png'%20%%7D` opens in your browser correctly? If it does not, then the problem is with how you are serving image files. You may need to adjust your Django settings to make this work correctly.

Comment: @Gunther, yeah. I changed path to `/static/img/myimage.png`. It's working fine now. By debugging in chrome, I replaced path in training dataset with the path of image, which is rendering properly. Thanks